# How to include code in a question at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design

When writing my problem and code at Stack Overflow, I'm having difficulty as a beginner at Stack Overflow to understand what HTML or CSS content to use to separate the normal text from code.

Comment: [It's called Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: you can use ``` for code parts. Like this ```code```.  ``` at the start of your and at the end.

Comment: It's called, I was also super confused when I started. What I do, for inline code, place a tilde in front of & after the code snipped: aka `code snipped example`. For other large chunks of code, paste in your code & make sure all lines are indented by 4 spaces.. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you search the help centre, this question will get closed quite quickly I am afraid as it is 'off topic'. top left of keyboard next to the '1' key is the tilde either side of inline code. For large blocks indenting by 4 spaces. For a snippet CTRL + M.

Comment: but but ... the editor provides buttons for that. With Tooltips that describe what each button does. And a preview, to check the output. It is not even necessary to learn Markdown. just select a section of your text and press the button.

Answer (score 0):

*```* 
At the start of the code

and *```* at the end of the code

Comment: While this is true I would add that those need to be on their own line and specially *before* the start of the code fench / code block there better be an empty line. Otherwise the quality checking regex might trip.